# How To Check Table variable is empty in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check whether table variable is **Nothing** in SQL Server.

I have used the following query

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Request)
BEGIN
   --Code here
END
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean a table variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way you did is correct but there's probably some clarification needed.

Table variables cannot be "nothing" or NULL. Once they are declared, they always exist. They may not have any records (in the same way as tables) but they exist.

Scalar variables can have a value of NULL.

Comment: Actually I'm Passing Datatable as values from .Net side, but now i need to send Nothing from .Net. so how can i check whether datatable is Nothing..

Comment: I cannot check it now as I don't have Visual Studio in front of me but I would suspect the table variable to still be there with no records.

Comment: It cannot be in SQL Server. Table variables cannot be null.

Answer (score 2):

T SQL is not an OO language, so Nothing is an unfamiliar concept here.

Table variables can be declared or not, and can have zero or more rows, that's it.

It's somewhat different from scalar variables, that can be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

correct me if i am wrong

the main objective of your code is to perform different operation based on table existance

if yes then maybe you can perform checking as below

```
IF @Request IS NULL
 (
     DO NOTHING
 )

ELSE
 (
   IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME = @Request)
       (
          DO SOMETHING
       )
   ELSE
      (
          DO SOMETHING
      )

 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 'TableVariableExists'
Where Exists (select 1 from @Requests)
```